# WPF ListView MVVM binding doesn't update UI

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding

Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

**ViewModelBase:**

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public sealed class PeopleViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ICollectionView _collectionView;
    public ICollectionView View => _collectionView;

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _personCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> PersonCollection
    {
        get { return _personCollection; }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._personCollection)
                _personCollection = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PersonCollection");
        }
    }

    private string _filterSearchText;


    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        _personCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        _collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(PersonCollection);

        Add(new Person() {FirstName="Homer"});
        Add(new Person() {FirstName="Bart"});
        Add(new Person() {FirstName="Lisa"});

    }

    public void Add(Person person)
    {
        PersonCollection.Insert(0, person);
    }

    public string FilterSearchText
    {
        get { return _filterSearchText; }
        set
        {
            _filterSearchText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FilterSearchText");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _collectionView.Filter = null;
            }
            else
            {
                _collectionView.Filter = x => 
                ((Person)x).FirstName.IndexOf(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly PeopleViewModel _peopleViewModel = new PeopleViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = _peopleViewModel;
    }

    private void MyUpdateLogic()
    {
        var person = new Person() {FirstName="Marge"} 
        _peopleViewModel.Add(person);
    }
    ...
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PeopleViewModel}}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="243" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="personListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Margin="0,0,0,5" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource CustomHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="20" />
                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"  
                             Handler="MyUpdateLogic" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox x:Name="searchTextBox" 
             Text="{Binding FilterSearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             MaxHeight="25" 
             MinHeight="25" 
             Height="25"
             Grid.Row="1" 
             VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The most interesting part that it shows initial list on the UI(Homer, Bart, Lisa), and even filtering works well, when I update `searchTextBox` it updates UI and shows only corresponding elements in the listview. But when I add new elements it doesn't update the UI, even though it really adds new element to observable collection `PersonCollection`.

What am I missing here? Also let me know if I implement MVVM pattern wrong.

**Update:**

Also I tried to bind to ICollectionView: `<ListView x:Name="personListView" ItemsSource="{Binding View}"`, it didn't work.

Tried to subscribe to Refresh in `PeopleViewModel` contructor:

```
_personCollection.OnChange += _collectionView.Refresh();
```

add refresh right after adding a new element to the list:

```
public void Add(Person person)
{
    PersonCollection.Insert(0, person);
    _collectionView.Refresh();
}
```

it also didn't work.

Comment: I assume you are using the ICollectionView in order to handle the filtering. Can you try: `_collectionView.Refresh();` after you have inserted the new `Person` into your `PersonCollection`

Comment: @Bijington, I tried that, please see updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the datacontext of the `Grid` twice, Just remove this Binding

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PeopleViewModel}}"
```

By adding this line in the MainWindow Constructor,

```
this.DataContext = _peopleViewModel;
```

you set the whole DataContext to bounded to this instance, you should know that the Datacontext Inherited from the parent control if you didn't override it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was my issue.